# A question about Egoroff theorem on a family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it possible to construct a family of measurable functions defined on a finite E that convergence is pointwise a.e. but Egoroff theorem does not hold?

I was hinted that it's relate to non-measurable set. To construct such functions converge pointwise but not converge in measure.

In other words, is there a family of measurable functions $\left \{ f_{t} \right \} _{t\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]}$ defined on $I=\left [ 0,1 \right ]$, while  $t\rightarrow 0, f_{t}(x)\rightarrow 0 $ a.e. but $\exists \varepsilon > 0, \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}m^{*}I\left ( f_{t}>\varepsilon  \right )\neq 0$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286142/lebesgue-integral-and-a-parametrized-family-of-functions